# Should I reuse a single instance of HttpClient on an ASP.NET Application that sends request to other APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, webapi, .net-4.8

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI application that uses HttpClient to send requests other APIs. Initially I registered my HttpClient in my dependency injection container as a single instance. But whenever I do that I get a timeout on the next request and will require me to restart the service to fix that.

I changed the registration to scoped so that every request that comes in will have their own instance of HttpClient if they need to. That seems to work fine but from what I'm seeing online, there should only be one instance of the HttpClient. But those examples doesn't say exactly if that's the same case with an ASP.NET application.

Did I do the right thing by creating a scoped instance of HttpClient?

I appreciate your suggestions for this scenario. Thanks!

*Note that I'm using ASP.NET (.NET Framework 4.8) and not .NET Core.*

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-7.0#typed-clients

Comment: I recommend using the typed client method

Comment: @Menyus That's for ASP.NET Core. This question is about the old ASP.NET Framework it seems.

Comment: In general, using a singleton instance of HttpClient is fine. If I recall right however, you won't pick up on DNS changes unless you restart the app then. Whether that's a problem for you depends on your specific use case. We get around all this HttpClient confusion on our team by using [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) instead, which handles the nuances for us.

Comment: Whops my bad, thanks for noting!

Comment: The timeout you're describing when using a singleton HttpClient is unusual. I would make a separate question asking about that specifically, making sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mason, I can post a separate question about that when I can produce a reproducible example. In my client, I'm sending 2-3 request on button press and those request will use httpclient.  Thanks!

Comment: I can confirm what @mason said is true (regarding DNS change). I also think the .Net team solved this in the framework area via httpclientfactory which is available as a .net standard nuget package. Might worth checking that out too.

Comment: I figured out what's wrong. I was downloading a stream using the httpClient and not disposing it. Leaving it open makes future requests timeout. So I guess I really don't need to create another instance of HttpClient. I used the IHttpClientFactory instead.